# Plot using go.Scatter() with entire dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

My csv is:

```
DateTime;S1;S2;S3;S4;S5;S6
2020-07-17 09:57:27.119916;725.9926027110598;730.5730869210306;946.2937510737263;542.341137182406;758.5531610786929;512.2027881299339
2020-07-17 09:57:28.119916;761.1846087077208;984.1009029835216;974.8724733720549;576.8019892357476;751.6553704523698;855.5439493088621
2020-07-17 09:57:29.119916;618.7837289058051;823.9970681226491;594.2841714340789;873.3093170922189;770.0875733375253;681.1715820388949
2020-07-17 09:57:30.119916;515.9456035777555;533.017970929369;639.3409213385498;542.4405737836958;514.4985515824058;650.5229638670448
2020-07-17 09:57:31.119916;589.1350057317254;605.703259361724;602.3181712775759;860.9749699475683;801.7960812507487;562.400896160191
2020-07-17 09:57:32.119916;626.2528314431347;615.7078057434281;643.2023497200336;709.6997180536518;741.365852401098;712.4384053449293
2020-07-17 09:57:33.119916;553.9768845577024;961.7714859567449;519.8207498752649;551.8006708566627;511.7426656331682;849.3428394570542
2020-07-17 09:57:34.119916;994.8208541190293;700.59423301376;569.1853469890981;997.5842090634065;621.2070112896865;848.5079857917269
2020-07-17 09:57:35.119916;502.2301607876932;760.8787524302393;671.2907579865052;669.0718770518221;901.3788876259023;926.077760311429
2020-07-17 09:57:36.119916;578.3978109170034;811.407262562966;822.6244615030105;570.0016494663124;935.0853062150045;689.8800124555897
```

I've read a csv file with this function:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_name, delimiter = ';', parse_dates=['DateTime']).set_index('DateTime')
```

`df` contains:

```
                                    S1          S2  ...          S5          S6
DateTime                                            ...                        
2020-07-17 09:57:27.119916  725.992603  730.573087  ...  758.553161  512.202788
2020-07-17 09:57:28.119916  761.184609  984.100903  ...  751.655370  855.543949
2020-07-17 09:57:29.119916  618.783729  823.997068  ...  770.087573  681.171582
2020-07-17 09:57:30.119916  515.945604  533.017971  ...  514.498552  650.522964
2020-07-17 09:57:31.119916  589.135006  605.703259  ...  801.796081  562.400896
2020-07-17 09:57:32.119916  626.252831  615.707806  ...  741.365852  712.438405
2020-07-17 09:57:33.119916  553.976885  961.771486  ...  511.742666  849.342839
2020-07-17 09:57:34.119916  994.820854  700.594233  ...  621.207011  848.507986
2020-07-17 09:57:35.119916  502.230161  760.878752  ...  901.378888  926.077760
2020-07-17 09:57:36.119916  578.397811  811.407263  ...  935.085306  689.880012

[10 rows x 6 columns]
```

So I want to use `plotly.graph_objs.Scatter()` to plot this data using the whole Dataframe but `Scatter` function request x [] and y [].

How can I plot this csv file getting on X axes `DateTime` and for each `S1,S2,S...` the Y value on X time using the entire Dataframe?

If is not possible, are there other ways using `Plotly` library?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. Were you trying to plot them to the same figure?
You can plot the data as dots by replacing `lines` by `markers`.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

file_name = "test.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file_name, delimiter = ';')

# Create figure
fig = go.Figure()

# Loop df columns and plot columns to the figure
for i in range(1, len(df.columns)):
    col_name = 'S'+ str(i)
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['DateTime'], y=df[col_name],
                        mode='lines', # 'lines' or 'markers'
                        name=col_name))

fig.show()
```

[image: plot of the dataframe]

Comment: It was great. Thanks, I would like to ask how can I do the same but in differents graphs? I mean in a matrix of plots, followed by each other. Similar to this: from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.2, figsize=(9, 9), diagonal='kde')

Comment: You could use Plotly subplots: https://plotly.com/python/subplots/ ! ```fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['DateTime'], y=df[col_name], mode='lines', name=col_name), row=i, col=1)``` You just need to define how many figures you want per row (```col``` value). This needs another loop or if statement. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this thread should contain an answer with `Plotly.Express`. With this package, a `Plotly.graph_objs` Figure is generated from the `DataFrame` you pass. You can do it like so:

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

file_name = "test.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file_name, delimiter = ';')

# Create figure
fig = px.line(
    df,
    title = "All curves in one diagram",
)

# Show figure
fig.show()
```

A shortcut (if you don't intend to modify the object `fig` in the future:

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

file_name = "test.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file_name, delimiter = ';')

# Create and show figure
px.line(
    df,
    title = "All curves in one diagram",
).show()
```

If you want the curves in six separate diagrams, `Plotly.Express` can be used in the same manner, but you have to make one `Figure` for each column of the `DataFrame`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

file_name = "test.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file_name, delimiter = ';')

for column_name in df.columns:  # this will be column_name =
                                # "S1", "S2", ..., "S5"
    # Create and show figure
    px.line(
        df[column_name],
        title = "Curve compiled from " + column_name,
    ).show()
```